# How do I create a URL to query Google places with the CID

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2, google-places-api

I have an app that searches the Google Places API and returns places based on categories that I choose.

The result is a JSON Object that contains a lot of data about each place.   I want to share this place via email with other people.   I extract the information I want from this object about the specified place by using the following code:

```
JSONObject geometry = (JSONObject) point.get("geometry");
JSONObject location = (JSONObject) geometry.get("location");
result.setLatitude((Double) location.get("lat"));
result.setLongitude((Double) location.get("lng"));
result.setIcon(point.getString("icon"));            
result.setName(point.getString("name"));
result.setVicinity(point.getString("vicinity"));
result.setId(point.getString("place_id"));
return result;
```

The place_id is the CID of the place, which is unique to the place.  I want to share this, or be able to show this place by going to Google Maps and search by this unique CID.  I construct the web browser URL as follows:

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/place?cid=ChIJgzzEJr9_24ARNu3LoImy7k4
```

This doesn't work though, and the web address gets converted to a lat/long, but no place shows here.

Is there an easy way to find a place on a Google Map using this unique CID?  Something like a URL that I can share with others in an email or something?  That way if I find a cool place and want to share it, I can just pass the URL with this CID?

Answer (score 2):

your "CID" is place id

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=YOURKEY&placeid=ChIJgzzEJr9_24ARNu3LoImy7k4

use this link, you can get json which contain all the information for this company, look the bottom of this json

```
"url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=5687679683593497910",
```

this is the TRUE cid!

Comment: How did you get the "TRUE" CID number?  I already get the information about the place when I query the Places API.   Shouldn't this data already be contained in the JSON object returned from the initial query?

Comment: you could get CID with place api, the "CID" on your code is the place-id which can be use for place api, then you could query this place-id's json, If you already get the result form place api for javascript, you could try, something like result.url

Comment: I already get the CID with the API via the place_id.  Shouldn't that "true" CID be located in the JSON object somewhere?  I am looking now and the data shows the following:

Comment: {"geometry":{"location":{"lat":33.49268879999999,"lng":-117.1473177}},"icon":"https:\/\/maps.gstatic.com\/mapfiles\/place_api\/icons\/generic_business-71.png","id":"01951b3af43717a7c474e0abf699ec400dddfdc7","name":"Art Y Culture","place_id":"ChIJgzzEJr9_24ARNu3LoImy7k4","reference":"CmRgAAAAsyXINdqYGzQ9Oy-TpDK0Lp515EOnYVggjvuZ1GmFONxt9j143AvYibhnAXwsDDPwQimfkXFm-mNY4-9uXvIUc0EkxxoSB-jpNZ-nrQO5piFXFAUk62-1YZsCUUQ1JIkYEhB8XH0oEx4ZCqeL-izTccNAGhTlTjWoozr-d3j2dCQ_ZWXblAtPow","scope":"GOOGLE","types":["art_gallery","point_of_interest","vicinity":"28690 Old Town Front Street, Temecula"}

Comment: Where did you get the "TRUE" cid from...the "5687679683593497910" number?

Comment: in my json       "place_id" : "ChIJgzzEJr9_24ARNu3LoImy7k4",
      "reference" : "CmRgAAAAioq5y6RkmLAxQpC5HoawB27G0lNks4Y8ihO5edVmpTU9aqyyC3ebmKDdp4BKAGbBl90Io0mi4OnBTIEChwjdC4BQO08Ij48dmOxCAi8RuVbII2LcAajikEw0UzbUCRPLEhCYfQ48NvS4_KleVv6m4-KIGhSACaH39hF066EQffDMCeMKHno_Iw",
      "scope" : "GOOGLE",
      "types" : [ "art_gallery", "point_of_interest", "establishment" ],
      "url" : "https://maps.google.com/?cid=5687679683593497910",
      "utc_offset" : -420,
      "vicinity" : "28690 Old Town Front Street, Temecula"

Comment: you cannot find URL on your json?

Comment: Not in the initial request.  I have to create a new request like this to get the URL response:  https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?key=YOURAPIKEY&placeid=THEPLACEID     Seems silly to have to create a second query and parse the JSON response to get the real CID/URL address from there.

Comment: As the documentation says, "A Place Search returns a list of places along with summary information about each place; additional information is available via a Place Details query."  Link: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

Comment: It doesn't work. placeid and cid seems to be different.